# CS0117: 'ProjectName.Droid.Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I just upgraded from MvvmCross 3.5.1 to MvvmCross 4.0. I'm getting around 40 errors like this when building Android in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

iOS works fine.

```
error CS0117: 'ProjectName.Droid.Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_seekBarStyle'
```

The line of code looks like this.

```
global::Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction.Droid.Resource.Styleable.Theme_seekBarStyle = global::ProjectName.Droid.Resource.Styleable.Theme_seekBarStyle;
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding multiple times as well as deleting bin and obj folders.

I've also removed the nuget packages and had them restored as well as reinstalled them but nothing seems to work.

I've tried updating AppCompat but it won't update, saying it couldn't find versions of Xamarin Forms compatible with the version, even though I have the latest version of Xamarin forms.

All my Android SDKs are up to date

Has anyone else encountered this error? If so, how did you resolve it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an old outdated package. Removing it fixed all the bugs.

Its called MvvmCross UserInteraction Plugin.